# Permutations in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am struggling to wrap my head around creating a permutation of a set in Elixir.

```
Permuate([1,2,3])
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

However each attempt I've come up with ends up with some similar version of:

```
[[2, [3, [1]], [1, [3]]], [3, [2, [1]], [1, [2]]], [1, [2, [3]], [3, [2]]]]
```

or

```
[[[2, [[3, 1]]], [2, [[1, 3]]]], [[3, [[2, 1]]], [3, [[1, 2]]]],
[[1, [[2, 3]]], [1, [[3, 2]]]]]
```

Which is almost there.. just need some enlightenment on constructing lists with Elixir.

My code looks like this:

```
defmodule Permutations do
    def permutate_set(s) do
        if Set.size(s) == 1 do
            Set.to_list(s)
        else
            Enum.map(s, fn(a) ->
                Enum.map(permutate_set(Set.delete(s, a)), fn(b) ->
                    [a] ++ [b]
                end)
            end)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get permutations of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756396/how-can-i-get-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- [Set is deprecated](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Set.html)
- [Use MapSet instead](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html)

Finds all perms:

```
defmodule Perms do
  def perms(%MapSet{} = set),
    do: MapSet.to_list(set) |> perms

  def perms([]), do: [[]]

  def perms(l) do
    for h <- l, t <- perms(l -- [h]),
      do: [h|t]
  end
end


defmodule PermsTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Perms

  test "find perms from set" do
    assert [[1, 2], [2, 1]] == Perms.perms(MapSet.new([1,2]))
    assert [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]] == Perms.perms(MapSet.new([1,2,3]))
  end

  test "find perms" do
    assert [[1, 2], [2, 1]] == Perms.perms([1,2])
    assert [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]] == Perms.perms([1,2,3])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the variable `b` in your anonymous function is already a list. By wrapping it in `[]` you are making it a list containing a list.

Comment: Apologies, I am not trying to nitpick - this answer looks like more of comment than answer.  If you wish, you can elaborate your suggestion and may be share corrected version of OP's code or your version of code for the benefit of future readers

Comment: @WandMaker I am addressing the specific issue in OPs code. The general case is already answered in the post Gazler linked above.