# Elixir: What does a multiple-generator list comprehension look like without the syntax sugar?

Tags: recursion, elixir, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand list comprehensions in Elixir.

The example I'm looking at is producing the permutations of a string from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756396/how-can-i-get-permutations-of-a-list/33769338#33769338).

```
def shuffle([], _), do: [[]]
def shuffle(_,  0), do: [[]]
def shuffle(list, i) do
  for x <- list, y <- shuffle(list, i-1), do: [x|y]
end
```

How does this double-generator comprehension look when re-written without the comprehension? I made an [attempt to implement the algorithm myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576511/1225617), but my implementation is appending to the list, rather than prepending as in the comprehension. I want to write the algorithm without the comprehension but with identical behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comprehension without filters can be converted into a sequence of `Enum.flat_map` and `Enum.map`. Specifically, all but the last one will become `flat_map` and the last one will become `map`. Here's a translation of your code:

```
list
|> Enum.flat_map(fn x ->
  shuffle(list, i - 1)
  |> Enum.map(fn y ->
    [x | y]
  end)
end)
```

I tested with `A.shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)` and the output looks identical to the original code in that question.

Answer (score -1):

Running Dogbert's example with the `flat_map` replaced with `map` really helped me see what was going on:

```
iex(1)> Permute.shuffle(~w(A B C), 3)
[
  [
    ["A", ["A", ["A"]], ["A", ["B"]], ["A", ["C"]]],
    ["A", ["B", ["A"]], ["B", ["B"]], ["B", ["C"]]],
    ["A", ["C", ["A"]], ["C", ["B"]], ["C", ["C"]]]
  ],
  [
    ["B", ["A", ["A"]], ["A", ["B"]], ["A", ["C"]]],
    ["B", ["B", ["A"]], ["B", ["B"]], ["B", ["C"]]],
    ["B", ["C", ["A"]], ["C", ["B"]], ["C", ["C"]]]
  ],
  [
    ["C", ["A", ["A"]], ["A", ["B"]], ["A", ["C"]]],
    ["C", ["B", ["A"]], ["B", ["B"]], ["B", ["C"]]],
    ["C", ["C", ["A"]], ["C", ["B"]], ["C", ["C"]]]
  ]
]
```

Comment: This should not be added as an answer.

Comment: I thought about making it a comment but then the example would be unreadable, or need to be left out.

Comment: E.g. update the question itself. Answers are supposed to be _answers_ for the sake of future readers. Or, _modify @Dogbert’s answer_.