# Iterating over list of tuples in elixir using Enum

Tags: list, tuples, elixir, enumeration

I am trying to iterate over a list of tuples through Enum.map .

```
coordinates = [{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}]
newcoordinates = Enum.map(coordinates,fn({X,Y})->{X+1,Y+1})
```

This code is not valid . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're missing an `end` after the function declaration. Second, in Elixir, identifiers starting with upper case are atoms and lower case are variables, unlike Erlang where upper case are variables and lower case are atoms. So you just need to make them lowercase:

```
iex(1)> coordinates = [{0, 0},{1, 0},{0, 1}]
[{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]
iex(2)> newcoordinates = Enum.map(coordinates, fn {x, y} -> {x + 1, y + 1} end)
[{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks , Uppercase was the problem . Missing end was a typo . Thanks for clearing that up .

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html):

```elixir
for {x, y} <- [{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}], do: {x+1, y+1}
```

Comprehensions are syntactic sugar for enumeration, so it's equivalent to using `Enum`.

Comment: FWIW, comprehensions are **not** a syntactic sugar, they are [transpiled into beams on their own](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/9d105ba4d655ecec00b10d35336a15c6b6d9922e/lib/elixir/src/elixir_erl_for.erl#L297-L300). Filters and multiple clauses in comprehensions are _not achievable_ with plain enumeration.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Although the official guide I linked to says they are syntactic sugar: "In Elixir, it is common to loop over an Enumerable, often filtering out some results and mapping values into another list. Comprehensions are syntactic sugar for such constructs: they group those common tasks into the for special form"

Comment: “such constructs” ≠ “enumerations” :)

Comment: About writing multiple clauses without the special form, I asked a question about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653654/elixir-what-does-a-multiple-generator-list-comprehension-look-like-without-the

Comment: It’s possible only unless you have filters/guards in the comprehension.