# Appending data to the list in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a function which looks like:

```elixir
def func() do
    list_z = [123]
    ...
```

I was looking to append the next data to this list like `list_z = [123, "abc", 190]`.

I tried using `List.insert_at`, append operators like `|`, `++`, `Enum.join`, ... but all of it just appends for that instance, the variable for next iterations returns back to `list_z = [123]`. I understand it's immutable but are there any other ways we could try something similar to this?

Edit 2:
What I did.

```elixir
def append_l(a,b) do 
    a = [b | a]
    Enum.reverse(a) 
    a 
    end                                                                                                  

def main(number) do  
    number = append_l(number,90)
    #next time number = append_l(number,"abc")
    end
```

Note: if I run the function once it does append `[123, 90]`, but if I loop it again it gets back to just one element(`number - [123, "abc"]`) in the list. I am looking for something like `[123, 90, "abc"]`

Edit3:

So I am working on something like

```elixir
def permutations(number) do
   #code to permuate all posibilities
end

def main(number) do
    Enum.each(Integer.to_charlist(number)), fn l ->
        #those satisfying the condition(the combination)
        #appending them to a list so that I have all the combinations
        #finding factors 
        #like number combination1 combination2 ...
    end
end
```

Edit 4:
I resolved the problem by replacing Enum.each to Enum.map

Comment: You are trying to learn a language without reading a book on the language.  If you get a book, read it, and do all the exercises, then you will learn the language.  If you just try to hack together code, it will take you much longer to grasp the underlying principles.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip https://twitter.com/mudasobwa/status/1140166401774239746 :)

Answer (score 1):

Elixir lists are linked-lists, and appending to them requires traversing the whole list each time. However, pre-pending to a list can be done in constant time.

The standard way to do this is to prepend to the list, and reverse the final result.

```elixir
list_z = [123]
list_z = ["abc" | list_z]
list_z = [190 | list_z]
Enum.reverse(list_z)
#=> [123, "abc", 190]
```

> it just appends for that instance, the variable for next iterations returns back to `list_z = [123]`

You need to rebind to the `list_z` variable, as in the above example.

Additionally, if `list_z` is declared outside of the function and you are trying to update it from inside `func/0`, that won't work. You need to pass `list_z` into the function, return a new list, and re-bind that to `list_z` outside of the function, like this:

```elixir
  list_z = [123]
  list_z = function_that_appends_some_stuff_to(list_z)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try out tr rebinding function but it still shows the same problem. Explained the situation now faced as Edit2 in the question. Thanks

Comment: Please re-read my answer. You cannot assign to a variable inside a function and use it outside of the function. You have just reproduced the same problem inside `main`. You need to *return* the variable, and assign to it outside of the function. So `number = main(number)`.

Comment: I think there's a bigger picture that's missing from your question. Could you explain what data you have, and what you want to get?

Comment: I hope this explanation works

Comment: Ah I see. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756396/how-can-i-get-permutations-of-a-list ?

Comment: It was not a similar problem, just had the same structure, but resolved it using Enum.map(). Thanks